# Selecting by attributes on features sharing common value

Tags: qgis, vector, select-by-attribute, expression, select-by-expression

I have a point vector with features sharing non-unique `"ID"`s. Each feature also has a `"distance"` field. I want to select among each set of features sharing the same `"ID"` only the feature with the minimum value.

Example:

| row | ID | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | One | 3.4 |
| 2 | One | 1.6 |
| 3 | Two | 5.4 |
| 4 | Two | 6.8 |

From the above, it should select rows 2 and 3.

I have seen similar questions that ask for the minimum value for each `"ID"`,  but I want to select the whole feature (because I need the coordinates of the feature).

I also know that this problem is trivially handled with `VLOOKUP` in Excel, but I want to streamline my workflow and so I am looking for a solution within QGIS.

Comment: Once you have the ID and min distance it is trivial to select the matching feature

Answer (score 5):

Use `select by expression` with this expression:

```
"Distance"=minimum( "Distance", "ID")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had tried to use that tool, but my expression was: minimum("Distance", "ID"). I didn't know I needed to add the '"Distance" =' part in front of it, so it didn't work.

Comment: Your expression selects the smallest Distance, grouped per ID. You now select all rows where this value *is equal* to the respective Distance

Comment: You're welcome. As a new user, please be adviced that this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it,  see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers